# overrideMaterial in CanvasRenderer

Tags: three.js

I fall back to CanvasRenderer if user's browser does not support WebGL.  I would like to have wireframe only rendering when using CanvasRenderer for performance reasons. However I cannot get overrideMaterial to work with it. It's working with WebGLRendererer quite nicely like this:

```
scene.overrideMaterial =  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true });
```

In CanvasRenderer this seems to have no effect, making FireFox unresponsive because the code is just too heavy for all but the simplest models.

Previously I had replaced all object materials directly with wireframe material by traversing the scene geometries and just overwriting the "real" materials. That kind of works, but  makes material and object management guite messy, as I would like to have the material information present in the models even if they are not rendered.

Is it possible use scene.overrideMaterial with CanvasRenderer? Or other way to force wireframe rendering? I'm using r54.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `CanvasRenderer` does not support `scene.overrideMaterial`. I think you have pretty much exhausted your options.

I would be careful about using `MeshBasicMaterial` as an override. Only do so if your scene contains meshes only -- no lines, for example.

three.js r.54

Comment: Well that explains it, thanks :S I can work around the issue, it's only quite a lot of work and more complexity. On the other hand if I implement overrides manually in my code, I can avoid any potential issues with MeshBasicMaterial (I have only meshes now, but probably also lines and stuff in the future).